# Set up a Red5 server with FFmpeg for live streaming to iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, red5, http-live-streaming

I'm an app developer and I need to implement FFmpeg to transcode/change an rtmp live stream to an http live stream so that I can play it on any iOS device (iPhone and iPad).

My problem is that I am fairly new when it comes to server, media stuff and FFmpeg. And I need to change the server so that I can transcode the live stream on the server side (which I have read that is possible). Any tips, suggestions, sample code, or tutorials would be of great help.

Answer (score 4):

For streaming to iOS devices via HTTP Live Streaming you will need to convert your media (FFMpeg can take live stream as input with rtmp://) using FFMpeg and then divide them into segments. [here is a link](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/) that can be of help. I haven't tried myself but I think you need to recompile FFMpeg. You could also try MEncoder.