# Live streaming HLS on Red 5 Media Server on Windows Server

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, red5, http-live-streaming

I am trying to develop a streaming server using Red 5 on Windows Server that would have two clients, a web app running on Windows 8 PCs and an iOS app.

The problem I'm facing is that iOS only supports HLS and Red 5 only supports RTSP/RTMP, so I need to convert incoming streams from HLS to RTSP/RTMP and outgoing streams from RTMP/RTSP to HLS using FFMPEG commands.  How would I go about this?  Should I modify the Red 5 server code or is there a better alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up a Red5 server with FFmpeg for live streaming to iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039805/set-up-a-red5-server-with-ffmpeg-for-live-streaming-to-ios)

Comment: There is a web Admin app in PHP/Node JS that would command Red 5 server to take incoming streams from attached Windows PCs on LAN OR iOS app and need to send trancoded streams to iOS app.Where do i call FFMPEG commands described in the link you gave and how should i achieve this ?